# Docker IPv6: Disable IPv4 in bridge docker0 and docker network

Tags: docker

I want to be sure that I'm no using a private network in docker bridge docker0 or the docker private networks. So for these interfaces I'm trying to use IPv6 only, but without disabling IPv4 on the host itself. (Which does not seam to help)

Is there a docker way to use IPv6 only in the docker networks?

I'm using docker 1.11.0